# Morphisms of elliptic curves which preserve identity are homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ and $E'$ be elliptic curves over a field $F$ and $h \colon E \to E'$ a morphism (i.e. everywhere defined rational map) such that $h$ takes the identity of $E$ to the identity of $E'$. I want to show that in fact $h$ is a homomorphism of ablelian groups. Apparently the key is to show that this diagram commutes:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\textrm{Pic}^0(E) @>>> E \\
@Vh_{\ast}VV @VVhV \\
\textrm{Pic}^0(E') @>>> E'
\end{CD}
$$
where the top map is the isomorphism which sends a divisor class in the Picard group to the corresponding sum of points under the group law on $E$, and similarly for the bottom map, and $h_{\ast}$ is the forward map $\sum n_P (P) \to \sum n_P (h(P))$ of Picard groups. Since the top and bottom are isomorphisms and $h_{\ast}$ is a homomorphism, if the above diagram commutes then $h$ is also a homomorphism. But if we follow the maps, the top map followed by $h$ is
$$\sum_{P \in E} n_P(P) \to h\left(\sum_{P \in E} [n_P] P\right),$$
(here I use the brackets to indicate addition in $E$), while $h_{\ast}$ followed by the bottom map[ is
$$\sum_{P \in E} n_P(P) \to \sum_{P \in E}[n_P]h(P).$$
But to say these things are equal is to say that $h$ is a homomorphism, so I don't see how we're supposed to show commutativity without assuming $h$ is a homomorphism. Since $h(0_E) = 0_{E'}$ we can show it for divisors of the form $(P) - (0_E),$ but how do we get it for all degree $0$ divisors?

Comment: Every degree $0$ divisor is linearly equivalent to one of the form $(P) - (0_E)$.

Comment: @André3000 Thanks, I remembered this fact this morning